# Define a Givens rotation (or Jacobi rotation) matrix of size M

Tags: matrix, rotation

I want to realize a function `R` with parameters `a, b, w` which creates an `M × M` Givens rotation (sometimes called Jacobi rotation) matrix; i.e., a matrix `R` of size `M × M` equal to the identity matrix except for the entries in position
`(a, a)`, `(a, b)`, `(b, a)` and `(b, b)` which are substituted with the entries of the matrix

```
{{Sin[w], Cos[w]}, {Cos[w], -Sin[w]}}
```

The solution I found is

```
R[a_, b_, w_] :=  Table[
   If[(m == a && n == a),
      Sin[w],
      If[(m== a && n == b),
         Cos[w],
         If[(m == b && n == a),
            Cos[w],
            If[(m == b && n == b),
               -Sin[w], 
               If[m == n, 1, 0]
            ]
         ]
      ]
   ], {m, 1, M}, {n, 1, M}]
```

but I wonder if there is a simpler/more efficient/elegant way to define the function.

Comment: `{{Sin[w], Cos[w]}, {Cos[w], -Sin[w]}}` is not a rotation matrix, since its determinant is not `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
givens[θ_, n_Integer?Positive, {j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive}] := 
       RotationMatrix[θ, {UnitVector[n, j], UnitVector[n, k]}]

givens[ϕ, 5, {2, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos (\varphi ) & 0 & 0 & -\sin (\varphi ) \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \sin (\varphi ) & 0 & 0 & \cos (\varphi ) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

As I noted in a comment to Henrik's answer, a simple way to generate a sparse version is the following:

```
givens2[θ_, n_Integer?Positive, {j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive}] :=
        With[{c = Cos[θ], s = Sin[θ]},
             SparseArray[{{j, j} | {k, k} -> c, {j, k} -> -s, {k, j} -> s,
                          Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}]]
```

or

```
givens3[θ_, n_Integer?Positive, {j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive}] :=
        With[{c = Cos[θ], s = Sin[θ]},
             SparseArray[{{j, j} | {k, k} -> c, {j, k} -> -s, {k, j} -> s,
                          {m_, m_} -> 1}, {n, n}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I really like `SparseArrays`, you know. Here is another proposal based on the answer by @J.M.

```
givens2[ϕ_, n_Integer?Positive, {a_Integer?Positive, b_Integer?Positive}] := 
  With[{ilist = Delete[Range[n], {{a}, {b}}]},
   SparseArray[
    Rule[
     Join[ Transpose[{ilist, ilist}], {{a, a}, {a, b}, {b, a}, {b, b}}], 
     Join[ConstantArray[1.,Length[ilist]], {Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ], Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}]
     ],
    {n, n}, 0.]];

Normal[givens2[0.25 Pi, 5, {2, 5}]]
```

> {{1., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.707107, 0., 0., -0.707107}, {0., 0., 1.,
>      0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0.707107, 0., 0., 0.707107}}

Of course, the *real* point of a Givens rotation is that it can be applied to vectors *without* creating any matrix.

Comment: Much shorter: `givens2[θ_, n_Integer?Positive, {j_Integer?Positive, k_Integer?Positive}] := With[{c = Cos[θ], s = Sin[θ]}, SparseArray[{{j, j} | {k, k} -> c, {j, k} -> -s, {k, j} -> s, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}]]`

Comment: @J.M. Ah, ingenius! I am not used to utilize patterns for creation of `SparseArray`s (I usually work with unstructured grids). I think you should post it! And that the `Band` entries for `j` and `k` are ignored is really subtle.